# Matplotlib won't follow date format set by set_major_formatter or set_minor_formatter for some datasets

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, matplotlib

I am using a program to make a plot of a pandas dataframe with date and time on the x axis and a variable on the y axis. I would like the plot to show the date and time for each tick on the x axis in yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm format.

Here is the code that I am using (I have hardcoded a simple dataframe to make this code easily reproducible). The below code displays [this figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sG1pf.png), which has the date and time format that I want.

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import dates as mdates

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [['2022-01-01 01:01', 5],
    ['2022-01-01 07:01', 10],
    ['2022-01-01 13:01', 15],
    ['2022-01-01 19:01', 10]], columns=['Time', 'Variable'])
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
df = df.set_index('Time')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'))
df.plot(ax=ax)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=45)
plt.show()
```

If I subtract one minute from each of the times and run the below code, I get [this figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmDYP.png), which has a completely different date and time format.

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import dates as mdates

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [['2022-01-01 01:00', 5],
    ['2022-01-01 07:00', 10],
    ['2022-01-01 13:00', 15],
    ['2022-01-01 19:00', 10]], columns=['Time', 'Variable'])
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
df = df.set_index('Time')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'))
df.plot(ax=ax)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=45)
plt.show()
```

I have changed nothing about the code except subtract one minute from each time, but the formatting of the ticks changes, even though I have used the set_major_formatter and set_minor_formatter methods to specify a format for each tick.

Is there a way to make sure the format for the ticks stays the same regardless of the dataset that is being plotted?

Comment: try changing the order of the commands and put `df.plot` before the formatters. Also use `which='both'` in your `ax.tick_params()` call.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Putting df.plot before the formatters does fix the problem in the example code I gave above. However, for the dataframe that I am actually using, if I put df.plot before the formatters, it gives an error saying "OverFlow: int too big to convert." That is why I had put the formatters before df.plot. When I do that, it doesn't give me any errors, but the correct date format isn't shown for some datasets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code below side steps the issue by avoiding the pandas plotting defaults.
You get the same x-axis format for all cases.

```py
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import dates as mdates

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [['2022-01-01 01:00', 5 ],
     ['2022-01-01 07:00', 10],
     ['2022-01-01 13:00', 15],
     ['2022-01-01 19:00', 10]], columns=['Time', 'Variable'])

df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'))
ax.plot('Time','Variable',data=df)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=45)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This code fixes the issue in the example I gave in my question. In my actual code, I would like the same plotting code to handle dataframes that have multiple columns of variables. The number of columns is not fixed either. For example, some dataframes will have only 2 columns while some will have 4 columns. Other than 'Time', the column names are also different each time. How could I extend this code to handle those cases? Once I set the index to 'Time', df.plot handled all of those cases well.